# How to wait on the data from net.socket to be fully submitted

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to receive a big JSON string from a Windows Application. However I can't seem to figure out how I need to wait on the data to be completely transmitted before I close the connection.

I've read that I need to wait on a callback, I've looked through the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) and I can't wrap my head around it.

I'm new to Node.js and Javascript programming in general so bear with me here.

```
client.on('data', function(data) {

    completeData = data;
    //Close the connection
    client.end();
});
client.on('end', function() {
    //Parse the data after receiving full json
    responseData = JSON.parse(completeData);
    console.log('Received data \r\n' + JSON.stringify(responseData,   null, 4));
    client.destroy();
    console.log('Connection closed');
    next();
});
```

EDIT:

I've tried this but it's still closes it before I get all the data.

```
client.on('data', function (data) {

if (newlineRegex.test(data)) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    responseData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('Received data \r\n' + JSON.stringify(responseData, null, 4));
    client.end();
}
```

});

EDIT: Adding full code, I must be missing something. 
If I add the doesn't work code it executes the JSON.parse to fast, if I do it doesn't parse it at all (Doesn't end up in the client.on('end'))

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var ServerConnection = require('server-connection')
var newlineRegex = require('newline-regex');

exports = module.exports = function (req, res) {

var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
var locals = res.locals;

// locals.section is used to set the currently selected
// item in the header navigation.
locals.section = 'server';
locals.responseData = new Object;
var completeData;

var net = require('net');
var client = new net.Socket('null', true);
client.connect(3333, '192.168.56.1', function (err) {
    console.log('Connected');
    //String test
    var string = '{"method":"getSerialisedDeviceInfo","params":[],"id":1}\r\n';
    client.write(string);
});
client.on('data', function (data) {
    completeData = completeData + data;
    console.log(completeData);
    //Doesn't work
    //if (newlineRegex.test(completeData)) {
        //client.end();
    //}
});

client.on('end', function () {
    //Parse the data after receiving full json
    responseData = JSON.parse(completeData);
    console.log('Received data \r\n' + JSON.stringify(responseData, null, 4));
    client.end();
    console.log('Connection closed');
    view.render('server');
});

};
```

Comment: you should not `end` connection in `data` event, because `data` is fired for every chunk of data you receive.

Comment: I do need to close the connection after I've received the data, so how do I go about that then?

Comment: You do need to close the connection, but after receiving all data. And that should happen in `client.on('end', function(){ })`

Answer (score 3):

There needs to be some kind of established protocol to determine the end of a "message" because TCP connections are *streams*. There are no built-in "message" boundaries like you have with UDP packets for example.

In the case of JSON, one popular and easy solution to this problem is to just use newline-delimited JSON strings. That way, all you need to do is continually buffer data until you see a newline, then you know you've reached the end of the JSON message and you can safely parse it at that point.

Comment: How do I accomplish that ? I've tried adding the above code, see edit.

Comment: In order for the newline delimiting solution to work, the other side has to *not* send formatted/"pretty-fied" JSON.

Comment: It just sends a string, that's why I stringify it to see if the data is properly formatted / in an object after receiving it. [Json](http://pastebin.com/3TKwR6MK)

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work. Let me know, if it doesn't work.

```
client.on('data', function(data) {
   //Parse the data after receiving full json
   responseData = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log('Received data \r\n' + JSON.stringify(responseData,null,4));

   client.destroy();
   console.log('Connection closed');
   next();
});

client.on('error', function(){
   console.log('error happened');
});
```

Comment: I never enter in the client.on('end') code this way. 
The net.socket keeps listening.

Comment: you can use `client.destroy()` in client.on('end')

Comment: Code in client.on('end') isn't getting executed. I don't know why.

Comment: I updated my answer. `end` event emits on client when other side of socket closes it. https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_data

Comment: `data` can be called multiple times.